# CORS in Nextjs Application on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch, next.js

I am currently working wiht my first bigger NextJS application and I ran into the classic CORS problem.

I have a backend, which is hosted on a different server/url, I get my json data from this backend.
My frontend written in NextJS is deployed on Vercel.

I do know, that I have to enable CORS both on the backend side, as well as on the frontend side, in my localhost dev, everything is working fine (even fetching data from backend)

I already followed this guide: https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-to-enable-cors, to enable CORS in my NextJS Application. I modified the nextjs config:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/.*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

However, when deploying the app on vercel, I receive the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://<my-censored-backend-url>' from origin 'https://<my-frontend-url>.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

In my backend (written in rails), I already configured my frontend on vercel to be allowed for CORS.
Is there anything I am missing?

Do you guys have any experience in CORS and fetching data for NextJS from a different server?
I am using getStaticProps, getServerSideProps AND SWR for fetching.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: CORS headers do absolutely nothing from the client (the HTTP *request* side). Use your browser Network debugging tab to see what headers are being returned from your server target.

Comment: So you suggest that the cause of the error must origin from the backend? 
Intresting enough, data through getStaticProps works, but not throughclient side calls

Comment: Do you see the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header present in the client-side requests in the browser's dev tools?

Comment: No, unfortunately the header is not there

Comment: So, every client side request should also contain the header explicitly? 

Currently I set the headers in the nextjs.config
Aren't CORS Headers only relevant for responses?

Comment: The network tab also displays that the preflite check (method OPTIONS) is also blocked

Comment: hey andread, have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem too where my website cannot request from my backend

Comment: So in my case, it definetly was the backends fault, make sure you allow the url of the page without using http or https, just the plain domain

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: In my case, it actually was a backend problem. To allow the correct page, only write down the domain inside the CORS Policy, not the whole url.
E.G. example.com instead of https://www.example.com

Comment: Any one got an idea what should be added instead of value in above code block?

Answer (score 0):

I think NextJS has a weird issue that sometimes it just throws the `CORS` error randomly.

In my case, with a wrong URL it will throw this `CORS` error.
For example, I used "https://localhost:3000" and then it throws the CORS error. And it worked with "http://localhost:3000".

So my suggestion would be to double check the URL that you are using.
Also, be sure to not include a trailing slash like "http://localhost:3000/" may not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).